# TRY Catch in procedure of SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating a stored procedure. It creates fine and it should save error message in DBErrors table if I give wrong values. Like in this case I am not giving int type value in employeeid.

It is not saving error values in the table DBerrors. Please guide me what’s wrong here?

I have already created employee and DBErrors table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SP_updateEmployee]
   (@EMPLOYEEID int, @NAME varchar(50), @ADDRESS varchar(50)) 

---add try catch in update statement
AS
BEGIN TRY
   update Employee
   SET employeeid=@EmployeeID,NAME=@Name,[ADDRESS]= @ADDRESS
where employeeid=@employeeID

END TRY

---stores error in error table
BEGIN CATCH


INSERT INTO DBErrors (USERNAME,ERRORNUMBER,ERRORMESSAGE)
VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(),ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_MESSAGE())



END CATCH


--drop PROCEDURE SP_updateEmployee

EXEC [SP_updateEmployee] t,'y','q' 

----select * from DBErrors
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error when you execute the stored procedure?

Comment: this will fail in the `EXEC` that calls your procedure, not in the procedure itself.  in short, it never gets to the `TRY` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error will be captured in **DBErrors** table only when the error/exception occurs within TRY block. In your case there is a possibility that user may pass string instead of INT, so the exception generated will be at parameter declare part which is out of your TRY block.

Soln: DECLARE @EMPLOYEEID VARCHAR(10)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SP_updateEmployee]
   (@EMPLOYEEID VARCHAR(10), @NAME varchar(50), @ADDRESS varchar(50))
```

Whenever user will pass string value as

```
EXEC [SP_updateEmployee] t,'y','q'
```

No exception will be generated at parameter declaration part and while inserting the value system will take care of throwing appropriate exception such as

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 't' to data type int.
```

As this is within your TRY block it will jump to CATCH block when exception is generated and you will be able to capture this data in your table.